# AjaxControlToolkit download

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, installation, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkitscriptmanager

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project which I am converting to Visual Studio 2015.

I have two questions:

1. The project is currently using AjaxControlToolKit 4.1.60501.0. Should I upgrade it to latest version AjaxControlToolkit 17.1.1? Would there be any coding changes?
2. I created a sample project and installed AjaxControlToolkit 17.1.1 from Nuget package. I see it in references and also all the Ajax controls in toolbox. However, I do not see ToolKitScriptManager. I also tried to install using exe from DevExpress etc. but still don't find ToolKitScriptManager.

Please guide how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your needs and your project structure.

We have upgrade guide for old versions: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below

You can get to know from there, that `ToolkitScriptManager` is removed, so you need to replace it with standard ASP.NET `ScriptManager`.

If you use `AjaxFileUpload` in your project, it's strongly advised to upgrade it to the latest version, because v17.1.1 contains major security fixes.

As a general rule, we advise you to use the latest version of the toolkit, because we can not deliver bug fixes and improvements to the old versions.